# Background or reasoning for error: TsLint: comment must start with lowercase letter

Tags: comments, typescript, tslint

I'm getting the following TsLint message in my project:

> TsLint: comment must start with lowercase letter

Is there any grounding behind this? I agree with most of what I've come across in TsLint, and I'm aware of the ability to turn this warning off.

I'd rather understand why they suggest this particular rule. I read the docs at https://github.com/palantir/tslint#supported-rules which explain what the rule does but not why.

Comment: I don't use Typescript, but I suspect there's a coding convention that makes special use of comments that start with capitals.

Comment: According to check-in history at https://github.com/palantir/tslint/commit/b85c254e98551ddb7199918b1b6d458e87875928 this rule was introduced by https://github.com/gscshoyru on Dec 2, 2013. Asking this question at the source might be the best way to get your answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I [asked the author](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/pull/43#issuecomment-67376310) on this one.

> This is just a style rule, and can safely be ignored if it's not needed

Personally speaking, I can think of no reason to enforce this rule so I recommend disabling it or ignoring it.

Comment: Wow, that is the dumbest style rule I can remember seeing. What kind of sense does it make to say "comments must not be complete English sentences?"  I think that "it's just a style rule" is not a good enough answer to "why did you think this was a good idea?"

Comment: As additional detail for people who want to leverage their IDE's "TODO" highlighting / processing, you *can* add words that it will ignore in the rules: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/comment-format/

Answer (score 0):

add this rule to your tslint.json:

```
"comment-format": [false, "check-uppercase"]
```